# convert temp from Celsius to Fahrenheit?

Tags: bash, shell, floating-point, arithmetic-expressions

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Enter degree celsius temperature: " C
F=$(1.8*{$C})+32
echo The temperature in Fahrenheit is $F
```

in above shell script i am trying to convert temp from Celsius to Fahrenheit

getting this error

> **/code/source.sh: line 3: 1.8*{32}: command not found
> The temperature in Fahrenheit is +32**

Ans should be 89

Comment: I think you are missing double quotes (") around your echo string.

Comment: Maybe `F=$(1.8*{$C})+32` should be `F=$(1.8*{$C}+32)` ?

Comment: As `bash` does not support decimal numbers, try `F=$(echo "1.8 * $C + 32" | bc)`.

Comment: `$(....)` does not do any arithmetic at all. `$((....))` would do integer arithmetic, but you want to have floating point. Either use `bc`, or switch to a shell/language which can do floats. I would recommend zsh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With bash only, and with a 0.1 accuracy:

```bash
$ cat c2f
#!/usr/bin/env bash

declare -i C F
read -p "Enter degree celsius temperature: " C
F=$(( 18 * C + 320 ))
echo "The temperature in Fahrenheit is ${F:0: -1}.${F: -1: 1}"

$ ./c2f
Enter degree celsius temperature: 32
The temperature in Fahrenheit is 89.6
```

If you are not interested in the fractional part but want a rounding to the nearest integer:

```bash
$ cat c2f
#!/usr/bin/env bash

declare -i C F
read -p "Enter degree celsius temperature: " C
F=$(( 18 * C + 325 ))
echo "The temperature in Fahrenheit is ${F:0: -1}"

$ ./c2f
Enter degree celsius temperature: 32
The temperature in Fahrenheit is 90
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `awk` for the floating point calculation and you can control the output format with `printf`:

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Enter degree celsius temperature: " c
awk -v c="$c" 'BEGIN {printf("The temperature in Fahrenheit is %.2f\n", 1.8 * c + 32)}'
```

or we can remove the `bash` parts and have an `awk` only solution

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {
    printf("Enter degree celsius temperature "); getline c;
    printf("The temperature in Fahrenheit is %.2f\n", 1.8 * c + 32)
}
```

Comment: put the read part also in awk..  `getline c < "-"`

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Enter degree celsius temperature: " C
F=`echo "1.8 * $C + 32" | bc`
echo The temperature in Fahrenheit is $F
```

Comment: If you want some stylistic tips/hints, paste your script there: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: F=`echo "1.8 * $C + 32" | bc`   for this line command not found error shows

Comment: there's is an start and end upticks for expression evaluation. 

F= ` echo "1.8 * $C + 32" |  bc `

Answer (score 0):

For 32 (°C) your formula `1.8*32+32` should yield 89.6 (°F) but as you mention *Ans should be 89* so we'll forget about the decimals and use `$((180*$c/100+32))` instead, so your program becomes (untested):

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Enter degree celsius temperature: " c
f=$((180*$c/100+32))
echo The temperature in Fahrenheit is $f
```

Output:

```
89
```

Basically Bash won't allow you to use decimals (1.8) but you can replace it with a fraction (180/100 or 18/10 or even 9/5, see the comments). Bash can compute with it but you'll lose the decimals (89.6 -> 89).

Comment: I'm curious why you went with `180/100` instead of `18/10`

Comment: 0°C = 32°F and 100°C = 212°F. 212-32=180 and 100-0=100. I've got some background in physics, really didn't even think about it. I've used to: _C_ × 2 -10% + 32 = _F_ in head, tho. 9/5 would've been even shorter.